# Accessing a data member of a pointer

Tags: c++

```
class Cat
{
  public:
    int name;
    Cat();
    int getName();
}
```

if I have a:

```
Cat* pointer = new Cat();
pointer->getName();
pointer->name; //this doesn't work
```

so how can I access the data member: name?

Comment: Can you copy the error you received?

Comment: What is it that "doesn't work" about it?

Comment: Either there's something obvious I don't see, or there's something you didn't write. That MUST work.

Comment: I bet it does work, it just doesn't _do_ anything.  What are you expecting it to do, in this case?  'getName()` is a function, and has some implementation that _does something_, while `name` is just a value, accessing it doesn't _do anything_ (like print it out).

Comment: It works fine.  You're either not showing us the real code, or you have something else going on.  Show us the error message and a complete testable example.

Comment: Pointers don't have members, the stuff they *point to* have members.

Comment: @0A0D constructor is not even required, let alone required in a specific order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works just fine: http://ideone.com/3E5Uec

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl;

class Cat
{
  public:
    int name;
    Cat() : name(0) { }
    int getName() { return name; }
};

int main()
{
    Cat* pointer = new Cat();
    pointer->name = 42;
    cout << "getName: " << pointer->getName() << endl;
    cout << "name: " << pointer->name << endl;
    delete pointer;
}
```

Note that I had to make some additions to the code that you provided, as it did not compile as you gave it:

- I added missing #include directives
- I added the definitions for Cat::Cat() and Cat::getName()
- I added the missing `;` after the class definition
- I wrapped your code in main(), and output the result of `pointer->name` to verify that it worked